# Hit a dead-end trying to learn classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, abstract

My fall semester will include working with c#, so I'm working to get a leg up while I can. The first thing I am trying to do is learn about abstract classes, but I'm having trouble making my code work. It's an "item" class, and there are 3 .cs files including the main project class.

Here is the abstract class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    abstract public class item
    {
        public abstract string prodName { set; }

        public abstract int amount();
    }
}
```

Here is the sub class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class ProteinPowder : item // Says it doesn't implement anything.
    {
        private string name;
        private int itemAmount;

        public proPowder(string name, int amount) // Is this correct?
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.itemAmount = amount;
        }

        public string Name { set => name = value; }
        public int Amount { set => itemAmount = value; }
    }
}
```

The main project is currently empty. I think the problems could be fixed by implementing ProteinPowder correctly, but I can't get it to work. Can someone point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

** EDIT ***

Does this look better?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class ProteinPowder : item
    {
        private string name;
        private int itemAmount;

        public ProteinPowder(string name, int amount)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.itemAmount = amount;
        }

        public int Amount { set => itemAmount = value; }
        public override string prodName { set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override int amount()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract classes in short are there to say "anything that implements me must provide an implementation for all abstract properties/methods i have".

In your case, `item` has 2 abstract items. `prodName` and `amount`.

This means in your `ProteinPowder` class, you need to implement these e.g.

```
public override string prodName { set => /*do something specific for ProteinPowder*/}

public override int amount()
{
    // do something specific for ProteinPowder
}
```

Your second thing you raise regarding `public proPowder(string name, int amount) // Is this correct?` and the answer is no.

I am assuming this is meant to be the constructor due to the lack of return type. The constructor must match the name of the class so this should read

`public ProteinPowder(string name, int amount)`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the information. I will see if I can get it to work now that I know what is wrong.

Comment: By the way...
>>Abstract classes in short are there to say "anything that implements me must provide an implementation for all abstract properties/methods i have".
 
That's the single most useful information I've gotten on abstract classes in all the videos I've watched and articles I've read.

Comment: Thanks for those words Jeffery :) glad it helped you out - of course there is a lot more to abstract classes than that single sentence so be sure to read up on abstract classes vs interfaces! Need anything give me a shout